# What is entity reference and Query Expression ? Please give some simple examples

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

What is EntityReference and QueryExpression? Please give me some simple examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EntityReference](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/using-the-365-entity-class-in-a-late-bound-fashion/)

> It is used for lookup fields in
>   365 – e.g. to link records via a 1 to many relationship. The lookup
>   field is shown on the ‘child’. You need to specify the ‘parent’ entity
>   type and record id.

[For example](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/create-retrieve-update-delete-365-data-in-a-late-bound-fashion/) if you are creating a accountand want to set the primary contact.

> ```
> Entity account = new Entity("account"); 
> account["name"] = "James Account"; 
> account["primarycontactid"] = new EntityReference("contact", contactId);
> service.Create(account);
> ```

[QueryExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.query.queryexpression?view=dynamics-general-ce-9)

> QueryExpression provides an object model to construct a query. Queries
>   can also be created using FetchXML, a proprietary XML based query
>   language.

For example of you wanted to retrieve all contacts full name and telephone number.

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
{
    Distinct = false,
    EntityName = Contact.EntityLogicalName,
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("fullname", "address1_telephone1"),
};
DataCollection<Entity> entityCollection = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;
```

Comment: Thanks James. Please tell me why you use Distinct = false?

Comment: That was just the example I used, there are lots of configurations, check out the documentation for further details, too much to reproduce here